# How to align the edge

Tags: edges, scale

How to align the edge in straight line. I tried align with S Y 0, The shape of my mesh got disturbed. Any way to align the edge without disturbing the mesh.

[image]

[image]

[How its working S Y 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWfYU.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying geometry is quite interesting and needs to be cleaned manually.

[image: Geometry]

You need to join vertices with <kbd>J</kbd> key to create clean lines. New edges are highlighted with red in the image below.

[image: Create these edges]

Next you need to dissolve remaining out of place edges shown in the image below. This can be done by selecting the edges, pressing <kbd>x</kbd> and selecting Dissolve Edges.

[image: Dissolve these edges]

The remaining line is quite clean.

[image: Cleaned geometry]

Comment: Did not work https://imgur.com/a/0NzX0GB

Comment: I edited the answer. This should work better.

Comment: UV for creative use of 'interesting' :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: Put the cursor on one of the boundary vertecies. Select the loop with opposite vertecy selected. Choose manipulation center to 3D cursor. Press S Y 0... tada.